# Run filter on SendLog data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is it possible to run a filter against the sendlog data extension in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

I've tried to create a filter, but I am getting an error when trying to save.

```
Error: Generic exception
```

I wasn't sure if this is expected results since the source of the filter is the **SendLog** DE.

**screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did get this error when trying to manually create a Filtered Data Extension from the SendLog DE - but then I tried creating a Filter and Filter Activity in Automation Studio - and it successfully created the FilteredDE. Funny thing was I couldn't find the Filtered DE using the UI even after refreshing - both in Email Studio and Contact Builder - but when I searched for the DE using the name, I could see the DE created. I then changed the folder of the DE to a subfolder and then was able to view it through the UI. Hope this helps.